# How to break cycle after a specific number of iterations in itertools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, cycle

I have a cycle that repeats, and I want it to stop repeating after let's say 5 repeats:

```
from itertools import cycle
a = [1,2,3]

for i in cycle(a):
    print (i)
    if i == 5:
       break
```

what I expect is `123,123,123,123,123`. it cycling 5 times before breaking. Instead it keeps going forever. How do I go about making it cycle only 5 times before moving on to the next code?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) show an equivalent generator function - you could use it and add a counter to the while loop.

Comment: You can use `itertools.repeat` for example: `for i in repeat([1, 2, 3], 5):`

Comment: @AndrejKesely you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools` provides *all* the tools here; just wrap in `islice` to limit the number of outputs (in this case to five times the number of inputs):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
a = [1,2,3]

for i in islice(cycle(a), 5*len(a)):  # Loops 15 times with a single value each time
    print(i)

# Or equivalently:
from itertools import chain, repeat

for i in chain.from_iterable(repeat(a, 5)):
    print(i)
```

If you just want the whole contents of `a` repeated three times (getting `[1, 2, 3]` on each loop instead of `1`, then `2`, then `3`), you'd use `repeat` instead:

```
from itertools import repeat
a = [1,2,3]

for x in repeat(a, 5):  # Loops five times, producing the same list over and over
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example `i` is one of the values from the list `a` and can never be `5`. You should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for such things:

```
from itertools import cycle
a = [1,2,3]

for index, element in enumerate(cycle(a)):
    print (element)
    if index == 5 * len(a) - 1:
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate as @Selcuk mentions in his answer or you can also use `next` to step the iterator until it reaches a given number of iterations.

```
import itertools
n = 5

a = [1,2,3]
g = itertools.cycle(a)

for i in range(n*len(a)):
    print(next(g))
```

You could also look into `itertools.repeat()` -

```
import itertools
n = 5

a = [1,2,3]
for i in itertools.repeat(a, 5):
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```